# getting relationship error without any relationships

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am seeing an exception from laravel:

`{"error":{"type":"LogicException","message":"Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Relations\\Relation"`

The strange part is that I do not have any relationships set up in the model that I am getting the exception on. I am only getting the exception when trying to save a model(update). It is saving, it just throws an exception also.

Model(very basic):

```
class Release extends Eloquent {

   protected $guarded = array('id');
}
```

Controller:

```
public function update(){
  $field = Input::get('field');
  $id = Input::get('id');
  $value = Input::get('value');
  $update = Release::find($id);
  $update->$field = $value;
  $return = $update->save;
  return Response::json($return);
}
```

I am not sure what I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the field names of your `table/model` and `$update->save` is missing the `()`, it should be `$update->save()`, for example:

```
public function update(){
    $field = Input::get('field');
    $id = Input::get('id');
    $value = Input::get('value');

    $update = Release::find($id);
    $update->{$field} = $value; // Make sure $field contains the field name
    $return = $update->save();
    return Response::json($return);
}
```

Comment: I guess I need to rest my eyes for bit...it was the missing (). thank you for seeing it!

Comment: Maybe you should sleep, Welcome :-)